# Printing an empty square made of letters using loops

Tags: java, loops

I need to be able to print this:

```
SQUARE
Q    Q
U    U
A    A
R    R
ERAUQS
```

But only have it down to asterisks as I don't know how to make it work with letters and don't know how print the word backwards

```
******
*    *
*    *
*    *
*    *
******
```

Could you explain what to do and how it works?

This is my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 6;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == size - 1 || j == 0 || j == size - 1) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: One idea is to treat the word as made up of an array of individual characters.  Find a way to replace the asterisk with the appropriate individual letter.

Comment: If you knew what `i` and `j` were, could you determine what character to print?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a two dimensional array of chars and place the appropriate character in the right coordinates of the 2D array.  Then you could modify your loops a bit to block the character from the 2D array grid.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int rows = 6;
    int columns = 6;

    char[][] array = new char[rows][columns];
    array[0][0] = 'S';
    array[0][1] = 'Q';
    array[0][2] = 'U';
    array[0][3] = 'A';
    array[0][4] = 'R';
    array[0][5] = 'E';
    array[1][0] = 'Q';
    array[2][0] = 'U';
    array[3][0] = 'A';
    array[4][0] = 'R';
    array[5][0] = 'E';
    array[5][1] = 'R';
    array[5][2] = 'A';
    array[5][3] = 'U';
    array[5][4] = 'Q';
    array[5][5] = 'S';
    array[1][5] = 'R';
    array[2][5] = 'A';
    array[3][5] = 'U';
    array[4][5] = 'Q';
    array[5][5] = 'S';

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (i == 0 || i == rows - 1 || j == 0 || j == columns - 1) {
              System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");  
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... don't know how print the word backwards ...
>
>
>
> Could you explain what to do and how it works? ..."*

You can utilize the *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* class, which has a *[reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse())* method.

Alternately, you can just iterate the characters of the *String*.

```java
String s = "SQUARE", r = "";
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) r = c + r;
```

Here is an example.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
String w = "SQUARE",
       ws = " ".repeat(w.length() - 2);
s.append(w).reverse();
for (int i = 1, n = w.length() - 1; i < n; i++)
    s.insert(0, "%s%s%1$s%n".formatted(w.charAt(i), ws));
s.insert(0, "%s%n".formatted(w));
System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
SQUARE
R    R
A    A
U    U
Q    Q
ERAUQS
```

As a note, it appears the left-side should be displaying the opposite characters.

In this case, use *n − 1 − i*.

```java
s.insert(0, "%s%s%s%n".formatted(w.charAt(n - 1 - i), ws, w.charAt(i)));
```

Output

```
SQUARE
Q    R
U    A
A    U
R    Q
ERAUQS
```

```
StackOverflow
t           o
a           l
c           f
k           r
O           e
v           v
e           O
r           k
f           c
l           a
o           t
wolfrevOkcatS
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just some good old plain string manipulation and loops, outputting just one character at a time?

For the vertical parts, the "left" variable starts at 1 and increases, while the "right" variable starts at `length() - 2` and decreases.

We're using `String.substring(someValue, someValue + 1)` to extract the single character at position "someValue".

Remember that the index position of the first character in a String is zero, and the index position of the last character in a String is `length() - 1`.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter phrase to make the square from: ");
    String phrase = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println(phrase); // top of square
    int number = phrase.length()-2;
    for(int left=1, right=number; left<=number; left++, right--) {
      
      System.out.print(phrase.substring(left, left+1)); // left side
      
      for(int spaces=1; spaces<=number; spaces++) {
        System.out.print(" "); // the empty middle
      }
      
      System.out.println(phrase.substring(right, right+1)); // right side
    }
    
    for(int i=phrase.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
      System.out.print(phrase.substring(i, i+1)); // backwards bottom
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
  
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter phrase to make the square from: BackToBasics

BackToBasics
a          c
c          i
k          s
T          a
o          B
B          o
a          T
s          k
i          c
c          a
scisaBoTkcaB
```